# WordPress: Inner-Page Linking, Pages based on Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to decide which method would be best for an internal linking structure that utilizes 4 main categories, and then pages within those categories using WordPress.

At first I thought I could just use Posts as a method of determining whether or not content belonged within that category... but now I'm second guessing myself. The site structure is like this:

High-level nab:

**Category 1**

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4

**Category 2**

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4

**Category 3**

- etc

**Category 4**

- etc

Obviously, this is a custom theme. But before I start coding, I want to make sure that I'm storing, pulling and organizing the data properly.

What are you thoughts? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is actually designed to be a blog, not a pure CMS. If you do not use the blog function, I suggest trying another 'real' CMS (Joomla, Drupal, TYPO3, many many others).

But to answer your question, why did you reconsider ? It would make it easier to know why your are second guessing...

If you want to accomplish this with the given categories from wordpress, you can use a category to page plugin like [this one here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page2cat/). But there are also some CMS plugins for WP that make wordpress to a proper cms and can help you grouping pages - see the plugin resource.

Comment: I started to second guess because there are a few plugins out there that associated categories to Pages. The other option is custom taxonomies.

Comment: I just ran across an incredible post: http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Lastnode/Wordpress_CMS

Comment: Yeah that's the choice... if you are lazy you should use the category to pages plugin, that way you have to code pretty much nothing about that. The custom taxonomies offer more versatility though, as you can call them directly way easier in your code.